# checking if Object children are null in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, if-statement

I have an object and I want to check if its fields are null or not and then I want to send a request. here is my code:

```
const [newProduct, setNewProduct] = useState({
    name: null,
    cost: null,
    size: null,
    color: null,
    material: null,
    discount: null,
    description: null,
    category: null
});

const addNewProduct = () => {
    if(newProduct.name && newProduct.cost && newProduct.size && newProduct.color && newProduct.material && newProduct.discount && newProduct.description && newProduct.category) {
        let productFormData = new FormData();
        productFormData.append('productInfo', JSON.stringify(newProduct));
        productFormData.append('productImages', images.imageFiles);

        const addUrl = "http://localhost:8080/cpnl/addproduct";
        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: addUrl,
            data: productFormData,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.msg);
            })
            .catch((response) => {
                console.error(response);
            });
    }
};
```

Is there a way to make if statement shorter?
do I need to define all fields to modify them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const nulls  = Object.values(newProduct).filter(p => p === null);

if (nulls.length === 0) {
   // save product
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. is defining object fields as null necessary?

Comment: in your case null is one method say what data initial not valid,   if for this data you have inputs,   you can use empty strings instead null,  and in filter write  p.length === 0  or p === ''

Comment: No I have inputa on seperate states and I will add them to the object on form submit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if every one of the object values is truthy.

```
const addNewProduct = () => {
    if (Object.values(newProduct).every(Boolean)) {
        let productFormData = new FormData();
        // ...
```